# How to check if all object with specific field name are true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with creating code.
First, here is a categories array with field property. The second array is an element of categories with a property field (this property is the same as in category so I can recognize which element suits to category).
How I can add property "edit" and "browse" to "categories" basing on elements of categories?
It's something like a global checkbox if all of the elements with a category for example "tags" have edit or browse true/false then add a property to this category.

```js
const categories = [
{
 name: "Tags",
 field: "tags",
//Here and in every object I want to add property edit: true/false, browse: true/false if all categoriesElements with field "tags" or other are true.
 hideFinance: false
},
{
 name: "Pixels",
 field: "retargeting_pixels",
 hideFinance: false
},
{
 name: "Dashboard",
 field: "dashboard",
 hideFinance: false
}
];

const categoriesElements = [
 {
   name: "Tags finance",
   field: "tags",
   edit: true,
   browse true
 },
 {
   name: "Tags channels",
   field: "tags",
   edit: true,
   browse true
 },
 {
   name: "Pixel creators",
   field: "pixel",
   edit: true,
   browse true
 }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A mix of two `for` loops should already get you the result you're asking for.

Comment: I tried soultion with for loop but here is a lot of object and im afraid about performance

Comment: Think about the performance if you have a running solution and a specialized tool (profiler) told you that there's a problem with that exact piece of script. Otherwise this is wasted time.

Comment: Also you have to iterate over all elements in `categories` and `categoriesElements`. There's no shortcut to the information _"every element in X has ..."_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `map` and `filter` to achieve this. Below is the example of how you use the map an array based on other array.

```js
const categories = [
{
 name: "Tags",
 field: "tags",
 hideFinance: false
},
{
 name: "Pixels",
 field: "retargeting_pixels",
 hideFinance: false
},
{
 name: "Dashboard",
 field: "dashboard",
 hideFinance: false
}
];

const categoriesElements = [
 {
   name: "Tags finance",
   field: "tags",
   edit: true,
   browse: true
 },
 {
   name: "Tags channels",
   field: "tags",
   edit: true,
   browse: true
 },
 {
   name: "Pixel creators",
   field: "pixel",
   edit: true,
   browse: true
 }
]


categories.map(cat=> {
    const ce = categoriesElements.filter(el=> el.field == cat.field);
    cat.edit = ce.length > 0 ? ce.every(elm => elm.edit) : false;
    cat.browse = ce.length > 0 ? ce.every(elm => elm.browse) : false;
    return cat;
})
console.log('categories', categories)
```

Comment: If you're not using the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool...

Comment: _"How to check if **all** object with specific field name are true"_

Comment: categories = categories.map((cat: any) => {
            const ce = data.filter((el:any) => el.field === cat.field);
            cat.edit = ce.every((ce:any) => ce.edit === true)
            cat.browse = ce.every((ce:any) => ce.browse === true)

            return cat
          });
It works

Comment: @R3muald Yes this will work but I guess you want false if there is no item on tag in categoriesElements array. So I have updated the answer according to that.